# Printing the results of an aggregate function from a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I retrieve the values of count in the cursor implementation using the record variable?

```
DECLARE 

   CURSOR cur_branch IS
    SELECT b.branchname, COUNT(a.applicantid) 
      FROM branch b, applicant a
     WHERE b.branchid=a.optedbranch
     GROUP BY b.branchname ORDER BY b.branchname;

BEGIN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Branch Name No of Applicants opted');

   FOR v_branchrec IN cur_branch
   LOOP

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(RPAD(v_branchrec.branchname,20)||'    '); 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_branchrec.COUNT(applicantid));

   END LOOP;

END;
```

This throws an error at `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_branchrec.COUNT(applicantid));` stating that COUNT has to be declared and it can be used only in SQL and not in PL/SQL.

I want to retrieve the number of students in every Branch.

Answer (score 0):

You should define an alias for `COUNT(a.applicantid)` and refer to this column through this alias.

```
 SELECT b.branchname, COUNT(a.applicantid) cnt FROM
...
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_branchrec.cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

1. Use an alias for the COUNT(a.applicantid) column in your cursor definition:

   ```
     SELECT b.branchname, COUNT(a.applicantid) as cnt
   ```
2. In the `LOOP` use

   ```
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_branchrec.cnt);
   ```